# Bars on chartjs superimpose when using type: 'time'

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to build a bar chart where the X-axis represents time.

However, when I use the option `xAxes: [{type: 'time'}]`, the bars start to superimpose, making a weird render.

When removing the option, the bars are displayed correctly, but the X-Axis labels are not displayed as dates

Am I missing something, or is it a bug ?

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0L071duj/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like chartjs is having a tough time getting the bar widths right on a dynamic x scale. A quick method to achieve what you want is to use the normal category scale on the x-axis and format the label at display time. To do that you `options` will look something like;

```
 options: {
     scales: {
       xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
           userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
             return moment(label, "YYYYMMDD").format("MMM DD, YYYY");
           },
         },
       }],
     }
   }
```

The `userCallback` function in `ticks` just has to return a string so you can format it however you want.

```js
 var labels = ["20170601", "20170602", "20170403", "20170503", "20170703", "20170404", "20170504", "20170704", "20170405", "20170505", "20170605", "20170705", "20170406", "20170606", "20170607", "20170608", "20170509", "20170609", "20170510", "20170511", "20170412", "20170512", "20170612", "20170413", "20170613", "20170414", "20170614", "20170515", "20170615", "20170516", "20170616", "20170517", "20170418", "20170518", "20170419", "20170519", "20170619", "20170420", "20170620", "20170421", "20170621", "20170522", "20170622", "20170523", "20170623", "20170424", "20170524", "20170425", "20170426", "20170526", "20170626", "20170427", "20170627", "20170328", "20170428", "20170628", "20170329", "20170529", "20170629", "20170330", "20170530", "20170630", "20170331", "20170531"],
   values = [5.79, 7.41, 7.08, 7.25, 7.46, 6.79, 7.01, 5.38, 7.35, 7.4, 7.1, 0.49, 7.57, 5.63, 4.15, 7.32, 5.55, 5, 3.26, 6.78, 2.75, 7.27, 7.33, 5.69, 7.1, 7.28, 6.85, 7.27, 6.4, 6.8, 6.9, 7.19, 3.97, 7.11, 6.89, 6.6, 4.03, 7.11, 5.49, 5.31, 2.43, 6.09, 6.14, 5.4, 3.7, 7.13, 5.72, 5.56, 5.4, 7.18, 7.08, 7.19, 7.39, 5.38, 6.96, 7.16, 5.34, 7.21, 5.98, 7.05, 7.32, 3.23, 6.88, 6.86];

 var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
     labels: labels,
     datasets: [{
       label: "Time",
       data: values,
     }]
   },
   options: {
     scales: {
       xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
           userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
             return moment(label, "YYYYMMDD").format("MMM DD, YYYY");
           },
         },
       }],
     }
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-wrapper">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but the timeline scale is not linear: there are no holes anymore for days without data.

Comment: True, I've played with the configuration as much as i can and it does seem to be an issue with chartjs that the bars are not displaying correctly. Maybe try submitting this as an issue on their github. In the meantime, you could always use a line graph, at least that way it won't look weird. Or pre sort the date labels that you feed to chartjs filling in gaps with null values in the data (both not ideal but unsure how long it would take for the bug to be fixed)

Comment: Thanks. I have submitted an issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4481